# How to pass values as arguments to a method in service class(POJO) without AXIS2

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

Actually I have a requirement in which an Android application will send some data by WebService. For that I prepared a service that I have mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705589/web-service-method-in-axis2-receives-null-arguments-why). I have seen similar posts in here but they too did not receive any suggestions. Some one is saying that there is a bug. Look for the reply in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682661/parameters-in-request-to-pojo-axis2-web-service-are-not-passed-to-the-pojo).

I have been trying this to make it work for the last two days. But no results.

I would like to know the other ways (i.e without AXIS2) by which I can do the same using Java WebServices.